# How to change date format in R

Tags: r

I have a table with 100k + observations. I would like to change the date formats from 20180104 to Jan 1st 2018. 
The table has dates from June 2017 till July 31st 2018.

When I try

```
SDM$Date <- format.Date(SDM$Date, "%d /%b/ %y"),
```

It says "invalid format"

Comment: Not sure, if there is an exact duplicate hence posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `as.Date` to convert string to Date and then use `format` to display it in the way we want.

```
format(as.Date("20180104", "%Y%m%d"), "%b %d %Y")
#[1] "Jan 04 2018"
```

Check `?strptime` to get list of all the formats you can pass.

In your case, it should be

```
SDM$Date <- format(as.Date(SDM$Date, "%Y%m%d"), "%b %d %Y")
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, but it still doesn't work. it shows Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @tegsim you showed your string in the format `20180104` and the answer works for it. Do you have the string in some other format? Can you post `dput(head(SDM$Date))` ?